# Multinomial logistic softmax regression with SGD

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, logistic-regression, gradient-descent

I'm trying to build a model from scratch that can classify MNIST images (handwritten digits). The model needs to output a list of probabilities representing how likely it is that the input image is a certain number.

This is the code I have so far:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
import numpy as np


def softmax(x):
    return np.exp(x) / np.sum(np.exp(x), axis=0)


digits = load_digits()

features = digits.data
targets = digits.target

train_count = int(0.8 * len(features))
train_x = features[: train_count]
train_y = targets[: train_count]

test_x = features[train_count:]
test_y = targets[train_count:]

bias = np.random.rand()
weights = np.random.rand(len(features[0]))
rate = 0.02

for i in range(1000):
    for i, sample in enumerate(train_x):

        prod = np.dot(sample, weights) - bias
        soft = softmax(prod)
        predicted = np.argmax(soft) + 1

        error = predicted - train_y[i]
        weights -= error * rate * sample
        bias -= rate * error
        # print(error)
```

I'm trying to build the model so that it uses stochastic gradient descent but I'm a little confused as to what to pass to the softmax function. I understand it's supposed to expect a vector of numbers, but what I'm used to (when building a small NN) is that the model should produce one number, which is passed to an activation function, which in turn produces the prediction. Here, I feel like I'm missing a step and I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest implementation, your last layer (just before softmax) should indeed output a 10-dim vector, which will be squeezed to `[0, 1]` by the softmax. This means that `weights` should be a matrix of shape `[features, 10]` and `bias` should be a `[10]` vector.

In addition to this, you should [one-hot encode](https://hackernoon.com/what-is-one-hot-encoding-why-and-when-do-you-have-to-use-it-e3c6186d008f?gi=ce250397ffae) your `train_y` labels, i.e. convert each item to `[0, 0, ..., 1, ..., 0]` vector. The shape of `train_y` is thus `[size, 10]`.

Take a look at [logistic regression example](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/2_BasicModels/logistic_regression.py) - it's in tensorflow, but the model is likely to be similar to yours: they use 768 features (all pixels), one-hot encoding for labels and a single hidden layer. They also use mini-batches to speed-up learning.